# How to get canonicalUrl in foursquare api?

Tags: java, foursquare, canonical-link

I'm getting CompactVenue result in api:

```
Result<VenuesSearchResult> result = foursquareApi.venuesSearch("" + lat + "," + lon, null, null, null, name, null, null, null, null, null, null);
```

Then I get ComapctVenue that I need and put it's ID to api to get CompleteVenue:

```
Result<CompleteVenue> completeVenueResult = foursquareApi.venue(ven.getId())
```

But my result doesn't contain canonical URL. Only short URL, name and ID.

How can I get canonical URL this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an api call to the [/venues/detail](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/40a55d80f964a52020f31ee3) API endpoint with the same venue ID. It has an attribute "canonicalUrl" which is the attribute you want.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Foursquare no longer suplies `canonicalUrl` element in its venue object.

Although you can still get from `menu.url` element.